# Labeling arrows with tikzpicture

Tags: tikz-pgf, arrows, tikz-arrows

I'm having trouble labelling the arrows. This is my code:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,minimum width=2em] { 
     \underleftarrow{lim}A_{i} &  \\ 
     A_j & A_k \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1) []
                edge (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge  (m-2-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

How can I label the arrows?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the powerful `tikz-cd` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\[
\begin{tikzcd}
\varprojlim A_i \arrow[d,swap,"\pi_j"] \arrow[dr,"\pi_k"] \\
A_j \arrow[r,swap,"\alpha_j^k"] & A_k
\end{tikzcd}
\]

\end{document}
```

By default, the label is placed on the left of the arrow (like left and right of a river are defined). With `swap` you exchange side.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

You want to put something below the lim operator with its arrow? Then it can/should be done in the math expression, `\mathop` turns the `\underleftarrow` expression to a math operator again:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,
    minimum width=2em] {
     \mathop{\underleftarrow{lim}}\limits_{\text{label}}A_{i} &  \\
     A_j & A_k \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge (m-2-1) []
                edge (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge  (m-2-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And labels for the other arrows can be inserted with `node`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,
    minimum width=2em] {
     \underleftarrow{lim}A_{i} &  \\
     A_j & A_k \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node[left] {label A} (m-2-1) []
            edge node[above right] {label B} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node[below] {label C} (m-2-2);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

And a `sloped` variant:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \matrix (m) [matrix of math nodes,row sep=3em,column sep=4em,
    minimum width=2em] {
     \underleftarrow{lim}A_{i} &  \\
     A_j & A_k \\};
  \path[-stealth]
    (m-1-1) edge node[sloped, below] {label A} (m-2-1) []
            edge node[sloped, above] {label B} (m-2-2)
    (m-2-1.east|-m-2-2) edge node[below] {label C} (m-2-2);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result sloped]

Comment: Thank you, your commet is useful. I think I did not ask my question properly. I would like to know how I can label the maps, for example the map going from the limit to the $A_i$ or the map $A_j \rightarrow A_k$.

Comment: @Guest Then I have misunderstood the question, see the updated answer for labeling the other arrows.